# Calling overridden method from within overriding method in OO PHP

Tags: php, oop, doctrine

Working in a symfony model, I want to override a function and call the overridden function from within the overriding one, along the lines of

```
class MyClass extends BaseMyClass {

  function setMyProperty($p) {
    parent::setMyProperty($p);
    //do some other stuff
  }

}
```

This is resulting in a segmentation fault. I don't want to alter the parent class - it's been generated by symfony, and may feasibly be overwritten in the future if the model is rebuilt. This seems like something that should be straightforward, but I'm struggling to find the solution.

Comment: This should not happen. Please provide more data about the error messages and check your log files for any additional information.

Comment: which PHP version are you using?

Comment: Note that this has noting to do with Symfony - that's Doctrine.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution to my own question on the [symfony project forum](http://forum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/94609/).

I can't call the overridden function because it doesn't exist. Though it exists enough for me to override it.

Using

```
$this->_set('my_property', $p);
```

Works where

```
parent::setMyProperty($p);
```

Causes the error.

Note that

```
$this->setMyProperty($p);
```

Works fine in my class if the method has not been overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Since you saw the problem, I guess you should mark it as answered to remove it from the unanswered list.

Comment: oooppzz, sorry, I was planning to add it as a comment. new user error.

Comment: I couldn't mark it as solved until 2 days after I posted the solution. Slipped my mind over the weekend - thanks for the reminder.

Comment: my pleasure. I was intrigue by the question and did not notice that you already had a solution that's why I made a reminder. :D